# How to pass "WriteThroughputBudget" config in Spark cosmosdb connector

Tags: apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the spark cosmosdb connector to write data in bulk to cosmosdb container. Since this is a bulk upload/write, and there are read operations happening at the same time. I want to restrict the RUs used by the write operation by spark connector. As per the wiki of the connector i found the config `WriteThroughputBudget` can be used to limit the write RUs consumption.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/wiki/Configuration-references

As per the wiki, `WriteThroughputBudget` is an integer value defining the RU budget the ingestion operations in a certain Spark job should not exceed.

I tried setting this config using the `option` in write dataframe as below

```
inputDataset.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").option("WriteThroughputBudget", 400).options(writeConfig).save()
```

Also, tried using the `options` in write dataframe

```
val writeConfig: Map[String, String] = Map(
      "Endpoint" -> accountEndpoint,
      "Masterkey" -> accountKey,
      "Database" -> database,
      "Collection" -> collection,
      "Upsert" -> "true",
      "ConnectionMode" -> "Gateway",
      "WritingBatchSize" -> "1000",
      "WriteThroughputBudget" -> "1000")
```

In both the cases write operation fails with excpetion

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:101)
        at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBConnectionCache$.getOrCreateBulkExecutor(CosmosDBConnectionCache.scala:104)
        at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBConnection.getDocumentBulkImporter(CosmosDBConnection.scala:57)
        at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBSpark$.bulkImport(CosmosDBSpark.scala:264)
        at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBSpark$.com$microsoft$azure$cosmosdb$spark$CosmosDBSpark$$savePartition(CosmosDBSpark.scala:389)
        at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBSpark$$anonfun$1.apply(CosmosDBSpark.scala:152)
        at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBSpark$$anonfun$1.apply(CosmosDBSpark.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1408)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I understand the value of the config `WriteThroughputBudget`, is Integer value. Even though I am passing the Integer as String, it should have implicitly casted it but if fails.

Is there any other way I can specify `WriteThroughputBudget` option.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/issues/139) answer your question?

Comment: Hi @SteveZhao, thanks its me only raising this question there as well. I tried and experimented with different version. Looks like there is something wrong with the specific release  version 3.0.5. azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-3.0.5-uber.jar

Comment: I post it as answer. Maybe this can benefit to others.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the specific release version 3.0.5. azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-3.0.5-uber.jar.

`WriteThroughputBudget` can work with below versions:

- azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-3.4.0-uber.jar
- azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-2.1.2-uber.jar
- azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-3.6.1-uber.jar